# Replacing a specific file in git submodule with a new version at build time

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am using an open source repo as a git submodule inside my own project.

Every time I build the whole project, I have to replace a specific file in the submodule with my own implementation. How can I do that without forking the open source repo? (The open source project is under heavy development and I get lots of conflicts when I add my own logic)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough info to be able to provide a concrete suggestion, but I'd be looking to see if there's any way that a solution could be found by extending/overriding the file in the underlying repo rather than replacing it, as I can't see that leading anywhere.

Comment: There is a particular class that actually I can override to provide my own implementation. How can I keep my own logic private while getting all the update from the open source repo?

Comment: I basically want to develop my own logic privately, get the most updated version of the open source repo, put these two codebases together and start building ad deploying.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't offer a way to let you do this natively.  The version of a submodule for a particular revision is fixed, and there isn't a way to replace files in the submodule the way that you want to without maintaining your own fork.

However, you can easily do this by changing how your build operates.  As part of your build process, you can copy all of the source files from one directory to another and replace or patch the files at that point, and then perform your build using the second directory as your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could use a little more info. There are multiple ways to solve your problem if i understand it correctly -

1. use a build script that overwrites the file in submodule and then invoke the actual toolchain to build.
2. Take a look at git post clone hooks.